# Different sample covariance formula demonstration

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, covariance

The formula for sample covariance is as follows:

$$cov_{x,y}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})}{N-1}$$

How do we show that it is equivalent to the following formulation:

$$cov_{x,y}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}y_{i}-\bar{x}\bar{y}}{N-1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the $n$ term in front of $\bar{x}\bar{y}$. Other than that the derivation should be along the lines:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
cov_{x,y} & = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})}{N-1} \\ 
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_iy_i - \bar{x}y_i - x_i\bar{y} + \bar{x}\bar{y})}{N-1}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i + n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{N-1}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i + n \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i}{N-1}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \cancel{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i} + \cancel{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i}}{N-1}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i }{N-1}\\
& = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_iy_i - n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{N-1}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: perfect, thank you very much!